# Hive Query Efficiency

Tags: sql, algorithm, performance, hive

Could you help me with a Hive Query Efficiency problem? I have two queries working for the same problem. I just cannot figure out why one is much faster than the other. If you know please feel free to provide insight. Any info is welcomed!

**Problem**: I am trying to check the minimum value of a bunch of variables in a Hive parquet table.

**Queries**: I tried two two queries as follows:

`query 1`

```
drop table if exists tb_1 purge;
create table if not exists tb_1 as
select 'v1' as name, min(v1) as min_value from src_tb union all
select 'v2' as name, min(v2) as min_value from src_tb union all
select 'v3' as name, min(v3) as min_value from src_tb union all
...
select 'v200' as name, min(v200) as min_value from src_tb
;
```

`query 2`

```
drop table if exists tb_2 purge;
create table if not exists tb_2 as
select min(v1) as min_v1
, min(v2) as min_v2
, min(v3) as min_v3
...
, min(v200) as min_v200
from src_tb
;
```

**Result**: Query 2 is much faster than query 1. It took probably 5 mins to finish the second query. I don't know how long will query 1 take. But after I submit the first query, it took a long time to even react to the query, by which I mean that usually after I submit a query, the system will start to analyze and provides some compiling information in the terminal. However, for my first query, after my submission, the system won't even react to this. So I just killed it.

What do you think? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query execution time depends on environment that you execute it.

**In MSSQL**.

Some people like you think query execution is similar to algorithm that they see in some *theoretical* resources, but in *practical* situation, it depends on other things.

For example both of your queries have `SELECT` statement that perform on a table and at first glance, they need to read all rows, but database server must analyze the statement to determine the most efficient way to extract the requested data. This is referred to as optimizing the `SELECT` statement. The component that does this is called the **Query Optimizer**. The input to the Query Optimizer consists of the query, the database schema (table and index definitions), and the database statistics. The output of the Query Optimizer is a **query execution plan**, sometimes referred to as a query plan or just a plan. (Please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide) for more information about query-processing architecture)

You can see execution plan in MSSQL by reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan) and I think you will understand better by seeing execution plan for both of your queries.

**Edit (Hive)**

Hive provides an `EXPLAIN` command that shows the execution plan for a query. The syntax for this statement is as follows:

```
EXPLAIN [EXTENDED|DEPENDENCY|AUTHORIZATION] query
```

A Hive query gets converted into a sequence of stages. The description of the stages itself shows a sequence of operators with the metadata associated with the operators.

Please see [LanguageManual Explain](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain) for more information.

Comment: .@Ali Soltani Thank you for the help. I am not using MSSQL though. It was executed in Apache Hive.

Comment: @Counter10000 I added new portion about `Hive` to my answer. Please see it again.

Comment: Great tips. I read the result from explain the queries. I don't understand the explanation yet. However, I notice one is much longer than the other, which may just simply infer that one is slower than the other. However, I am still trying to figure out the reason behind it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What is surprising?  The first query has to read `src_tb` a total of 200 times.  The second reads the data once and performs 200 aggregations.  It is a no brainer that it is faster.

Comment: .@Gordon Linoff  Partially true. In first query I read the same table 200 times, but every time I read only one attribute. In the second query, I scan the table once but need to sort the table 200 times, one time with one attribute only.

Comment: @Counter10000 . . . Hive does not necessarily use columnar data stores, so it depends on the storage engine you are using.

Comment: .@Gordon Linoff Thanks. I read wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS). In my understanding, if it is a big database, then columnar data store is more efficient for analytic queries in most of the time. However, in my case, I cannot distinguish which one (column or row-oriented data store) is quicker. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Counter10000 . . . Columnar stores are generally better for querying. It is much harder to implement that ACID semantics for them.

Comment: .@Gordon Linoff Thanks. I mean can you explain why columnar data store matters for my queries? I still think it takes the same time for the two queries to run through, no matter it is a column or row oriented data store. Could you explain a little bit more in my example, for my queries?

Comment: One thing is clear that since you are using min which is an aggregate calculation , columnar database is more appropriate for you. Have you tried removing the  'v1' as name, etc from your first query?

Comment: @Fact May I ask why would you suggest to remove the 'v1' as name?